# При добавлении нового ключа, перезатирается старый Bundle

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. Есть такой код.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(AppContext.ACTION_TYPE, AppContext.ACTION_UPDATE);
bundle.putInt(AppContext.DOC_INDEX, ((ToDoDocument) parent.getAdapter()
        .getItem(position)).getNumber());

intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Создаю объект `Bundle`. Добавляю. туда данные ключ - значение и передаю это все активити.

Так вот кода я добавляю второй раз в `Bundle`, старый ключ - значение перезатирается, а нужно что бы добавлялся. Может зря я связался с этим `bundle`, как можно передать несколько параметров в другое активити.

```
intent.putExtra(AppContext.ACTION_TYPE, AppContext.ACTION_NEW_TASK);
```

вот так передаю один параметр, а как передать два?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интересная закономерность: ищу ошибку около часа, не могу, как только задам тут вопрос - сразу же нахожу ошибку.

`AppContext.ACTION_TYPE и AppContext.ACTION_TYPE` имели одинаковое значение, а это ключ, и он должен быть уникальным. Я проглядел это.

Comment: >Моя кошка замечательно разбирается в программировании. Стоит мне объяснить проблему ей - и все становится ясно.

John Robbins, Debugging Applications, Microsoft Press, 2000

Comment: Jeff Atwood как-то писал, что один из когнитивных принципов, на которых стоит SO - это то, что в процессе словесного описания вопроса человек часто находит ответ, и эта выпадающая менюшка с похожими вопросами появилась не просто для какого-то улучшения юзабилити на бумаге, а для финального пинка пользователя к ответу.